# Problema com Activity Java em Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-activity

Boa tarde, estou enfrentando um problema que sempre que atualizo dois nós diferentes no Firebase de uma única véz, a `Activity` simplemente abre novamente se sobrepondo à `Activity` atual. Segue o código abaixo do método chamadao.

```java
private void incluiProduto() {
    try {
        final String dataCadastro = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyy HH:mm:ss").format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
        precoProduto = Double.parseDouble(editTextPreco.getText().toString());


        mapVenderProduto = new HashMap<>();

        mapVenderProduto.put("chaveProduto", chaveProduto);
        mapVenderProduto.put("chaveVendedor", chaveVendedor);
        mapVenderProduto.put("fotoVendedor", fotoVendedor);
        mapVenderProduto.put("latitude", latitude);
        mapVenderProduto.put("longitude", longitude);
        mapVenderProduto.put("nomeVendedor", nomeVendedor);
        mapVenderProduto.put("precoProduto", precoProduto);
        mapVenderProduto.put("telefoneVendedor", telefoneVendedor);

        mapProdutos = new HashMap<>();

        mapProdutos.put("chaveProduto", chaveProduto );
        mapProdutos.put("nomeProduto", nomeProduto);
        mapProdutos.put("precoProduto", precoProduto );
        mapProdutos.put("fotoProduto", fotoProduto);
        mapProdutos.put("unidadeMedidaProduto", unidadeMedidaProduto );
        mapProdutos.put("dataCadastro", dataCadastro);
        mapProdutos.put("marcaProduto", marcaProduto);

        DatabaseReference dadosRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        Map<String, Object> mapDados = new HashMap<>();
        mapDados.put("produtos/" + chaveProduto + "/vendedores/" + chaveVendedor, mapVenderProduto);
        mapDados.put("vendedores/" + chaveVendedor + "/produtos/" + chaveProduto,  mapProdutos);
        dadosRef.updateChildren(mapDados);
        finish();

    } catch (Exception ex) {
      ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Eu quero quero feche a Activity sempre que a função que for executado o metodo.

Answer (score 0):

Faça dessa forma, quando for passar pra próxima Activity:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Activity2.this, Activity3.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | 
Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
```

Colocando essa Flag, você limpa a pilha de Acitivitys que estão acumulando.

Comment: Não deu certo. Deixa eu explicar melhor. Em ItensActivity tenho um ListView que ao clicar em um item específico abre VenderProdutoActivity na forma de um popup. ItensActivity não quero que seja fechada e por isso não dou um finish nela. Ao executar o método incluiProduto() a partir do evento onclick de um botão em VenderProdutoActivity deveria simplesmente fechar, porém o que está ocorrendo é que se eu executar duas atualiazações ao mesmo tempo no Firebase,  VenderProdutoActivity fecha e  ItensActivity abre novamente se sobrepondo a uma ItensActivity já aberta.